# How do you become a moderator for this site?

Tags: support, moderation

I am glad to be a part of a new Stack site. I do not mean to say *I want* to be a moderator -- I do not have credentials that others have pointed out. And I do not know as much as others.

I am asking this question because I have not been a part of a beta on SE before. I see mods everywhere on established sites..

Comment: SE is like any other community-driven site. The people who 'stand out' as exceptional community members are usually chosen for moderators and such. You have, so far, asked 2 questions (1 main, 1 meta), and provided 1 answer. Talking about becoming a moderator with those 'community credentials' (so to speak) is something I find a bit odd ... If that's accepted, then basically anyone could become a moderator and gets deletion privileges and other tools we only want responsible people to have ... do you think that that's a good idea *on the internet*, of all places?

Comment: You're right, asking to become a mod is a little much. I edited the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The site is currently in private beta, and has no moderators. If the site moves to public beta, then after a little while short-term moderators will be selected. The criteria for selection is outlined in [this StackExchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

If the site were to move out of beta, moderators would be elected by the community.

The relevant criteria for the pro tempore moderator position is to:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community

Comment: Thank you. As I said in in my question, I am just worried about not gaining rep -- I know plenty about Vim, but not as much as others... I see you already have over 1000 rep.

Comment: @onebree You get reputation by answering questions. You haven't answered any, so I would encourage you to try :-) And it's not like everyone else knows exactly what they're writing the moment they see the question, I often have to look up stuff & experiment ...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I guess it is harder for me to gain rep on SO -- so many questions are above my head, and I am only pretty good at one language (Ruby).

Comment: I would just like to point out that one's reputation points has very *little* to be with moderator selection. We look at *broader* participation, which includes things like resolving meta issues; leaving helpful, thoughtful comments to guide users; etc. Asking and answering questions is where the reputation points come from, but there's a whole other side of vetting and curating content that is not reflected in the reputation system, and those activities have a much stronger correlation to being a good community leader.

Comment: @RobertCartaino looking at that post, I have opened a [question for nominations](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/190/who-are-our-nominees-for-the-moderator-positions). But now I wonder, is that still recommended?

Comment: I don't think it really matters until we know if we're leaving private beta or not.

Comment: @muru Yes, it is still recommended that the early community initiate this.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Aargh. I just deleted it since http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta says it's for public betas. Should I undelete?